# CodeIgniter copying an instance - performance issues?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have quite a few libraries and models that get loaded into a controller, and each library/model creates an instance of CI using `$this->CI =& get_instance();` in the `__construct` function.

Are there any performance issues with this and is there a better way?

Comment: The `&=` makes it very likely that what is being passed is actually a reference to the object, not a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That class is using the **[Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)**. It is not creating multiple instances, it is just returning you the **same/one** instance of the CodeIgniter to be used. So no performance issues there.

Comment: Ok great, the comment above that line says 'Copy an instance of CI so we can use the entire framework' I guess that is misleading...

Comment: @fire: yes even comment says "not a copy", you should study about the Singleton pattern i have given the link of in my answer. Thanks